# keydown and toggle variable's value increase 1 and toggle to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

set up of element i will use in my project

```
  function bossShanLi() {
  const shanLi = 'Shan-Li',
  user = '史豔文';
  var click = false;
  var userBlood=100;
  var attack = document.getElementById('attack'),
   defense = document.getElementById('defense'),
   items = document.getElementById('item'),
   magic = document.getElementById('magic'),
   overPower = document.getElementById('over-power');
   yushan = document.querySelector('#yushan');
```

this function is to rotate 3d like css's rotate3d and i have set var x y z and than i set specific key press down the x will become 1 and y and z but it is not working

```
   function rotate3d(e){
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0; 
    var z = 0;
    document.onkeydown = function(){
    if(e.keyCode === 65){
        x = 1;
        console.log(e.keyCode);
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 83){
        y = 1;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 68){
        z = 1;
    }
}
          var degree = e.clientX||e.clientY;
          yushan.style.transform='rotate3d('+ x +','+ y +','+ z 
         +','+degree+'deg)';
```

below this is just as console log i make it a span and innerHTML to see the value and what;s going on

```
   let number = document.querySelector('.number');
    number.innerHTML='degree'+':'+e.clientX+','+e.clientY+','+degree+ 
    'x'+':'+x+'</br>'+'y'+':'+y+'</br>'+'z'+':'+z;
    }

     window.addEventListener('mousemove',rotate3d);
   }
   window.onload=bossShanLi;
```

Comment: Ok. What is your question ? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: my question is i want to make keypressdown keycode A and variable x will become 1 and after i press again it will turn back to 0 , so i can have rotate3d css method toggle x ,y and z their all 1 to 0, but my writing to is wrong so i think someone can help me out how to write the correct function.